# AngularJs: Two nested child state but different views

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Good day mate, just want to ask something i stumbled on some issue in angular routing. my goal is to make a routing which has two children state but different views. for example:

```
    var parentState = {
        name: "parent",
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "src/views/parent.html",
        title: "Login Page",
    }

    var childState = {
        name: "parent.child",
        url: "child",
        templateUrl: "src/views/child1.html",
        title: "Login Page",
    }

    var child1State = {
        name: "parent.child",
        url: "child",
        templateUrl: "src/views/child2.html",
        title: "Login Page",
    }

    $stateProvider
    .state(parentState),
    .state(child1State)
    .state(childState);

the tree looks like this
                   parent
             child        child
          SomeViews      AnotherViews
```

is this Doable? thanks

Comment: no, its not possible to rout two different view for same routing url

Comment: thanks for the info sir @azad, but is there any hack or solution to this? i have a page which has two ui-view as children and i want them both to show at the same time.

Comment: You can have two named ui-views as targets for a given level you just can't have one ui-view with two things targetting it.

Comment: Hi sir @shaunhusain yes i have two ui-views inside my parent. but it has error already constructing in angular maybe because its imposible to have two state with the same url. so i think the solution is to make another url for the other children. but the problem is how can i open them both

Comment: See the answer below, once you have different named views you just have 1 state that defines multiple templates/controllers etc. for the different named views.  If in some case you only want to show something in one of the views I believe you can just target that view in the state definition and leave the other blank or give it an empty string for the template.  So to clarify you just use 1 state but have multiple template definitions etc. for each target ui-view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var parentState = {
    name: "parent",
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "src/views/parent.html",
    title: "Login Page",
}

var childState = {
    name: "parent.child",
    url: "child",
    views {
       'firstPlace':{templateUrl: "src/views/child1.html"},
       'secondPlace':{templateUrl: "src/views/child2.html"}
    },
    title: "Login Page",
}

$stateProvider
.state(parentState),
.state(childState);
```

Where parent.html has

```
<div ui-view="firstPlace"></div>
<div ui-view="secondPlace"></div>
```

Comment: no problem glad to help especially when I don't have to look anything up :)

Comment: can i ask one last question? i tried to put a link inside "firstPlace" view with ui-sref but nothing is happening after clicking it.

Comment: Make sure you use the full state name unless it's relative to the current state ui-sref is probably getting confused, ui-sref should add an href based on finding the state by name and it's corresponding URL but if you are in some view believe the ui-sref is relative unless you give it a full state path from the "root" state down

Comment: hi @shaunhusain  maybe you can help thanks :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48110133/angularjs-multiple-netsed-ui-views

Answer (score 0):

You need to paste following code:

```
$stateProvider
                .state('parent.child', {
                    url: '/child',
                    cache: false,
                    views: {
                         'firstPlace':{templateUrl: "src/views/child1.html"},
                         'secondPlace':{templateUrl: "src/views/child2.html"}
                    }
                })
                .state('parent', {
                    url: '/parent-content',
                    templateUrl: 'src/views/parent.html',
                    abstract: true
                })

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/parent-content/')
```