# Angularjs: Multiple netsed ui-views

Tags: angularjs

Good day mate i have few more questions about angularjs routing.
How does ui-sref works inside nested angularjs views. i have no problem nesting views in my codes below, the problem is when i start to use ui-sref inside those views.

My goal is to change the content of ui-view="child1" from child.html template to "thirdChild" state template when i click the "Child State" tag as you can see i put ui-sref in there,tried my best but somehow its not working. hope somebody can help me thanks in advance.

HTML files :

```
index.html:
<div ui-view></div> <!-- Parent view -->

<!-- parent content -->
parent.html 
<h1>Parent State</h1>
<div ui-view="child1"></div> <!-- Child view -->
<div ui-view="child2"></div> <!-- Child view -->

<!-- child content -->
child.html
<h1 ui-sref="parent.child.third">Child State</h1>

<!-- child content -->
child1.html
<h1>Another Child State</h1>
```

My Angular Routing:

```
    var parentState = {
        name: "parent",
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "src/views/parent.html"
    }

    var childState = {
        name: "parent.child",
        url: "child",
        views: {
           'child1':{ name: "parent.child.child1", templateUrl: "src/views/child.html" },
           'child2':{ templateUrl: "src/views/child2.html" }
        },
        title: "Login Page",
    }

    var thirdChild = {
        name: "parent.child.third",
        url: "/child3",
        template: "<h1>Another Child</h1>"
    }

    $stateProvider
    .state(parentState)
    .state(childState)
    .state(thirdChild);
```

Comment: Ui-sref only works on anchor tags by adding a href they won't work on a h1 wrap the header tag in an anchor and use the ui-sref on that

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: Right click the element and hit inspect element see if an href has been added.

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/Q2FtQZ/ see examples here